# How to let not all the data show up using a choice field but only the ones related to the choice field in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have this website which has one purpose which is viewing data out of a database according to the related topic chosen by the user. I have managed to make the data show up, but all the data found in the database is showing up when I click on the viewing button paying no attention to the chosen topic. I am not sure if it is because of how I have organized the database or if the problem is with my forms.

This is the model that I am using:

```
    from django.db import models
    from home.choices import *

    # Create your models here.

    class Topic(models.Model):
        topic_name = models.IntegerField(
                        choices = question_topic_name_choices, default = 1)
        topic_question = models.ForeignKey('Question',
                                        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                        blank=True,
                                        null=True)
        topic_answer = models.ForeignKey('Answer',
                                        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                        blank=True,
                                        null=True)
        def __str__(self):
            return '%s' % self.topic_name

    class Image (models.Model):
        image_file = models.ImageField()

        def __str__(self):
            return '%s' % self.image_file

    class Question(models.Model):
        question_description = models.TextField()
        question_answer = models.ForeignKey(    'Answer',
                                        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                        blank=True,
                                        null=True)
        question_image = models.ForeignKey(    'Image',
                                        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                        blank=True,
                                        null=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return '%s' % self.question_description

    class Answer(models.Model):
        answer_description = models.TextField()
        answer_image = models.ForeignKey(    'Image',
                                        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                        blank=True,
                                        null=True)
        def __str__(self):
            return '%s' % self.answer_description
```

This is the views file:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response, redirect
    from .choices import *
    from django.views.generic import TemplateView
    from home.models import Topic, Image, Question, Answer
    from home.forms import TopicForm


    class QuizView(TemplateView):
        template_name = "index.html"

        def get(self, request):
            form = TopicForm()
            args = {"form": form}
            return render(request, self.template_name, args)

        def post(self, request):
            form = TopicForm(request.POST)
            if  form.is_valid():
                form = TopicForm()
            posts = Question.objects.all()
            args = {"form": form, "posts": posts}
            return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

This is the forms file:

```
    from django import forms
    from betterforms.multiform import MultiModelForm
    from .models import Topic, Image, Question, Answer
    from .choices import question_topic_name_choices

    class TopicForm(forms.ModelForm):

        class Meta:
            model = Topic
            fields = ['topic_name',]

    # 'class': 'home-select-one'
```

> By the way how can I add this `class` into the `ChoiceField`?

This is the html file:

```html
        {% extends 'base.html' %}
          {% block content %}
          <h4>International Baccalaureate Physics</h4>
                <form  method="POST">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                  {{ form.as_p }}
                  <button type="submit" id="home-Physics-time-button">It is Physics Time</button>
                </form>
                {% for post in posts %}
                <table style="margin: 10px auto; width: 90%; line-height: 35px;">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td style = "border: 2px solid #ffffff; padding: 1%;"> <strong>Question:</strong> <br>{{ post.topic_question}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td style = "border: 2px solid #ffffff; padding: 1%;"> <strong>Answer:</strong> <br>{{ post.topic_answer }}</td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                {% endfor %}

            {% endblock content %}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `posts = Question.objects.all()` shouldn't you apply your TopicForm as a filter here?

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view.py, you want to apply the selection made in the `TopicForm` correct?
So something in this direction is needed. You'll need to double check what the `cleaned_data` of the TopicForm has exactly.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response, redirect
from .choices import *
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from home.models import Topic, Image, Question, Answer
from home.forms import TopicForm


class QuizView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "index.html"

    def get(self, request):
        form = TopicForm()
        args = {"form": form}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)

    def post(self, request):
        form = TopicForm(request.POST)
        posts = Question.objects.all()
        if form.is_valid():
            # Apply the selected topic as filter on all the posts.
            # TODO: Figure out what the exact value is you get from the form.
            posts = posts.filter(question_topic__topic_name=form.cleaned_data['topic_name'])
        args = {"form": form, "posts": posts}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

Comment: I have been trying to fix it for a while and it is not working, and by the way the fields that I want to retrieve are `question_description ` and `answer_description `
Do you think that my model is made correctly for this purpose?

Comment: I have written it like this but it is not working:
`posts = posts.filter(topic_name=form.cleaned_data['topic_name', 'question_description', 'answer_description'])`

Comment: Yes, did you try looking what is in `form.cleaned_data`? It will be a dict containing the fields of your `TopicForm`. So looking at your code it would contain the selected `Topic`'s `topic_name`. I updateted my answer a little bit. You can filter `Question` via the FK `question_topic`'s `topic_name` attribute.

Comment: I have changed the models and included two `ForeignKey` inside of the `Topic` class so I might get the results. And this is how I have added the code into the views. `posts = posts.filter(question_topic__topic_name=form.cleaned_data['topic_name', 'topic_question', 'topic_answer'])` and yet I am receiving an error at `post` I don't understand why you have two `__` at `question_topic__topic_name` Thank you!

Comment: Can you update the post? The double `__` is used for look-ups. In this case we lookup `topic_name` of the foreign key field `question_topic`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Comment: Sir, I have gone back to the original model because it doesn't work for my database to be like the upgraded one. However, I don't know what to do and even my way of asking is not that profession as well. Thank you very much for the help, I am truly thankful.